# How can I see the mounted volumes from the Desktop in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: 19.04, gnome-shell, desktop-icons

Currently, I have Ubuntu 19.04. I wanted to know how I can see the mounted volumes from the desktop. Apparently, they removed [the option from GNOME Tweaks that allowed it to be enabled in previous releases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKLZI.png), but perhaps there is another way to achieve it.

I have only these options available for the 'Desktop Icons' extension (the option of mounted volumes is *not* included):
[image: available options for 'Desktop Icons' extension]
([link to the original screenshot by OP in Spanish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUYNR.png))

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  I'm a little confused by "devices mounted from the desktop" and "options that allowed it to be enabled".  Can you give an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: You can open a `Files` (Nautilus) window and you can see them in the left pane.

Comment: You can try the **Removable Drive Menu** _GNOME Shell Extension_.

Comment: I just uploaded an image where the available options come out. The option of mounted volumes is not included.

Comment: [https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/7/removable-drive-menu/]

Comment: I already tried the extension and it seems fine, but what I really want is that the mounted volumes appear on the Desktop as in previous versions of Ubuntu. I want something like this: https://imgur.com/bBn8Sir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 19.04 and Gnome desktop icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135565/ubuntu-19-04-and-gnome-desktop-icons)