# Ability to drag and drop files on Desktop to other apps

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, drag-and-drop

On 18.04 and 18.10 I was able to drag for example a file that was on the Desktop and drop it in the Telegram app, Google Drive and so on. Now on 19.04 it does not allow for drag and dropping of files from the desktop to another app. Is there a setting for this since this behavior would be unintuitive for a normal user.

The image below is to give an idea. I grab a file, drag it to, for example, Telegram, and instead of detecting that I want to drop it, it simply shows as hovering the area. This happens on Google Drive, Gmail and other apps when dragging from the desktop. It works if I do it from the file app (Previously Nautilus) but not directly from the Desktop which will create issues when explaining ubuntu to others.

[image]

Comment: drag and drop functionality from the desktop doesn't exist on ubuntu 19.04 this was known even before it would release. it's a WIP although I've heard you can install other desktop handlers in the meantime.

Comment: [This one](https://askubuntu.com/q/1136203/480481) probably is a different question, according to OP: "can no longer drag and drop anything (ie, files, windows, etc.) with the touchpad. I can, however, move things around using the touchscreen" An [answer posted there](https://askubuntu.com/a/1136471/480481), however, looks like an answer to this question.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135565/ubuntu-19-04-and-gnome-desktop-icons

Comment: Looks like it but the answer is not what I am trying to find out. Actually, the answer totally deviates from what the question was trying to reach and it still got accepted. So was this caused by gnome 3.32?

Comment: @Luis Actually Nautilus lost desktop icons feature since v3.28, [these are the reasons](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/158) GNOME developers cited. To compensate Ubuntu shipped 18.04 and 18.10 with Nautilus v3.26 instead of the later ones. Now 19.04 comes with Nautilus v3.32, so it lost the desktop-icons feature. Icons are now provided by a GNOME shell extension instead, which doesn't provide all the features as before.

Comment: Do not get me wrong, but I can recommend to drop this modern great and glossy Nautilus and install normall fully functional file-manager Nemo or Caja instead. Or drop GNOME and install Cinnamon or MATE instead. GNOME became unpredictable and painful.