# Dragging from Gnome's Google Drive broken

Tags: gnome, firefox, 20.04, google-drive

Dragging from Gnome's Google Drive to firefox creates reference to extensionless temporary file.

Copying works correctly.

Is there a solution to this?

Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does dragging to another applications work? To know if it is a Firefox or a Gnome issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "Gnome's Google Drive"?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani No, it doesn't work to any.

Comment: @N0rbert If you add a google account to Ubuntu you can choose to access files, via Gnome AFAIK. That is what I meant.

Comment: You could change your question to something like "Unable to drag from Gnome's Google Drive". Otherwise, people that do not know about Firefox will not even read it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I tested, with a pdf file, the behaviour of transferring files from Google Drive, from a connected Google account, depends on what applications you are using.

If I work with source and target Nautilus windows, I can either Copy-Paste or Click-and-Drag, and the name is correctly kept.
It appears integration with Gnome, which has Nautilus as its file manager, works well.

If I work with source Nautilus and target Dolphin (the KDE file manager) windows,
Click-and-Drag uses the temporary file name in the target,
while
Copy-Paste sometimes produces that same result and sometimes does not even work ("unable to create io-slave klauncher said unknown protocol 'google-drive'").
I didn't investigate further.
`kio-gdrive` is required for KDE applications to interoperate with GDrive, but I did not try that either.

As for Click-and-Drag from Nautilus to a Gmail composition as an attachment in Firefox that doesn't work for me.

**EDIT**:
[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145385/ability-to-drag-and-drop-files-on-desktop-to-other-apps) suggests you *might* have more luck trying a different desktop manager, but it seems like a big change (and merely an attempt), if only motivated by the drag-and-drop feature between different applications for GDrive.

**EDIT #2**:
As a possible *workaround*, you may have two Nautilus windows #1/#2 open.
You would drag from GDrive in #1 into a local temp folder in #2.
Then you would drag from #2 into your gmail composition.

Comment: I am dragging a png to a mail in mail.google.com. Even just dragging the file to firefox gives a weird name "file:///run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=emmanuelbendavid/0B0UkQ6gHvW-TbVpmREZmYW1qY2M/0B0UkQ6gHvW-TdGJCMFhpdWFmazA"

Comment: @EmmanuelMess - I guess you are out of luck with Gnome.

Comment: Where do I report this issue?

Comment: In this case, the problem is at the interface between Gnome and Firefox.
It is not clear who should/will face it.
In the case of Dolphin that I mention, it is KDE who provided the package.
[This](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/users/auth?next=%2Fen-US%2Fquestions%2Fnew%2Fdesktop%2Fform) is the community support for Firefox. It is a likely appropriate first step prior to filing a bug.