# upgraded to 19.04: unable to disable desktop icons

Tags: gnome, 19.04, desktop-icons

I have upgraded to 19.04 few weeks ago, I never asked to use desktop icons feature but after the upgrade, the icons appears.

It is disabled in gnome-tweaks: Trying to turn-on/turn-off does not change anything. Disabling the extension support does nothing either.

I tried via gsettings as

follow:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-home false
```

It hides the icons for 1s, then reappears. Looks like it gets reactivated automatically.

I tried also to reset the settings through gnome-tweaks: no chance.
Same for resetting gnome, no chance.

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome
```

Funny enough, people complains about the opposite: icons disappeared after upgrade.
[Ubuntu 19.04 and Gnome desktop icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135565/ubuntu-19-04-and-gnome-desktop-icons)

Consistency...

note: "Hello board" <-- this part does not appear in the message despite edition. So, everyone: Hello :)

Comment: Were you able to find some solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on ubuntu 19.10 and had the same problem. The only way I managed to disable it is to add `['desktop-icons@csoriano']` to `/org/gnome/shell/disabled-extensions` via the dconf Editor.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works in ubuntu 19.04 too `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false`

Comment: nope, unfortunately.
I will go back to 18.10 or LTS,  disappointing