# Ctrl + Shift + m works in the folders, but not on the Desktop to create shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, 19.10, shortcuts, desktop-icons

I'd like to create a desktop shortcut of a folder by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>; the problem is that this key-combination works in the folders, but not on the desktop. How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ) . Desktop without desktop is not desktop, simply ignore GNOME Shell.

Comment: Hello @N0rbert can you describe the action suggested in your link please?v In particular what's GNOME shell and what are the disantvantages if i remove it?

Comment: GNOME Shel is current [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) of Ubuntu. It loses functionality nowadays. My main reason to mark this as duplicate is to say that it is impossible to get standard desktop options while using GNOME Shell. Personally I would recommend to remove GNOME Shell and install MATE DE instead. But you may prefer Xfce or KDE desktop environments.

Comment: @N0rbert thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, unless you contribute to further development of the Desktop Icons Gnome Shell extension.

Since a few Ubuntu versions, the icons on the desktop are not anymore provided by the file manager, nautilus. A quite new Gnome Shell extension has been developed to provide icons on the desktop. However, this desktop extension still is limited in many aspects, and is not (yet?) capable of replicating all functionality/workflows/hotkeys of nautilus.

So you are limited as of now to use the right-click menu to create new folders directly on the desktop.

If this is critical to your workflow right now, you may consider [substituting nautilus with nemo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135565/ubuntu-19-04-and-gnome-desktop-icons), or even choose to use a different desktop environment that fully supports icons on the desktop.

Comment: So we need extensions to use desktop on Ubuntu Desktop. Holy molly, it is 2020 year.

Comment: @N0rbert Yes, totally, What a mess! Why shouldn't the *specific file manager application* handle the *desktop* environment's desktop?! That sounds sooo normal. Some stupid user once [demonstrated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Spp1WrGEdyM) how installing (an older version of) Nautilus via WSL hijacked the desktop of, wait for it, *Windows 10*; but those are some silly talking points. After all, GNOME sucketh soooo much! :)